# How to hide particular data to expose in server side datatable processing

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring-mvc, datatables

Currently I am doing datatable server side ajax processing. Scenario is:

1. As like normal datatable operations i.e. sorting-searching-pagination.
2. one Column(say the last one) with action header will contain the action buttons like ADD/EDIT/DELETE/MARK/CACHE etc.
3. Based on user role and its access permission user can access particular buttons which is assigned by admin. For Example,

   User with Role=1 has ADD-EDIT button enabled.
   User with Role=2 has EDIT-DELETEbutton enabled

When userrole 1 or 2 is logged in user can see and access only that buttons.

If I pass the access information from JSP's(getting info from session object) script tag to main javascript function and with If-Else condition it can be done.BUT the access information is exposed to client.

REQUIREMENT: I want to create buttons dynamically but in server side(Java-Spring) or hiding the logic from user.

so far this is my try:

script.js

```
 function getDatatable(id, url, columns) {
        globalDatatable = $('#' + id).DataTable({
            lengthChange : false,
            processing : true,
            serverSide : true,
            order : [ [ 0, 'asc' ] ],
            paging : true,
            fnDrawCallback : function(oSettings) {
            },
            ajax : {
                url : url,
                type : "GET",
                datatype : "application/json",
                data : function(d) {
                    return JSON.stringify(d);
                }
            },
            initComplete : function(settings, json) {
            },
            columns : columns,
        });
    }
function getIpRangeDatatable(id,url){
    var columns=[];

    columns.push({ data: "ipid" ,name:"ipid"});
    columns.push({ data: "startIp",name:"startIp" });
    columns.push({ data: "endIp",name:"endIp" });
    columns.push({ data: "allow",name:"allow" });
    columns.push({ data: "roleName" ,name:"roleName"});
    columns.push({ data: "description" ,name:"description"});
    columns.push({ data: "loginId",name:"loginId" });
    columns.push({ data:function(o1){ return parseDateTime(o1.fromDate); },name:"fromDate" });
    columns.push({ data: function(o1){ return parseDateTime(o1.toDate); },name:"toDate" });
    columns.push({ data: function(o1){ 
          var buttons=[{name:"Edit", action:"doOperations(2,12,3,"+o1.ipid+")"}
          ,{name:"Delete", action:"doOperations(3,12,4,"+o1.ipid+")"}];
          return getActionMenus(buttons);
        }});

    getDatatable(id,url,columns);
}

function getActionMenus(buttons) {
var menu= "<div class='btn-group'>"+
"<button type='button' class='btn btn-default'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-share' aria-hidden='true'></span> Action</button>"+
"<button type='button' class='btn btn-default dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'> <span class='caret'></span> <span class='sr-only'>Toggle Dropdown</span> </button>"+
"<ul class='dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right'>";
for(var i in buttons ){
    menu+="<li><a href='javascript:"+buttons[i].action+"' data-title='IpRange'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit' aria-hidden='true'></span>"+ buttons[i].name+"</a></li>";
}
menu+="</ul></div>";
return menu;
}
```

Test.jsp

```
<%
    String ctxPath = request.getContextPath() + "/";
    String id = "ipRange_" + Utils.getUUID();
%>

<div class="wrapper-content-area-pad">
    <div class="panel panel-primary flat-panel">
        <div class="panel-heading flat-panel">IP Range Details</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
        <a href="javascript:doGenericOperations(2,12,3,0)"class="btn btn-default" data-title="IpRange">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>Add IP</a>

            <table id="<%=id%>"
                class="table compact table-striped table-bordered table-action" cellspacing="0"
                width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>IPId</th>
                        <th>Start IP</th>
                        <th>End IP</th>
                        <th>Allow Rule</th>
                        <th>Type of User</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>From Date</th>
                        <th>To Date</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        getIpRangeDatatable('<%=id%>', 'appAdmin/s/manage_ip/datatable/1');
    });
</script>
```

JSON data sample:

```
{"draw":1,"recordsFiltered":6,"data":[{"ipid":11,"startIp":"172.16.0.0","endIp":"172.16.255.255","allow":0,"allowNull":false,"description":"Faculty ip range ","roomId":0,"roomIdNull":false,"fromDate":null,"toDate":1474889095000,"userId":9295,"userIdNull":false,"roleName":"Faculty","userRoleId":4,"userRoleIdNull":false,"loginId":"shylaja.sharath@pes.edu"},{"ipid":12,"startIp":"10.10.101.10","endIp":"10.10.101.10","allow":0,"allowNull":false,"description":"Tech team Ubuntu","roomId":0,"roomIdNull":false,"fromDate":null,"toDate":null,"userId":0,"userIdNull":true,"roleName":"Student","userRoleId":3,"userRoleIdNull":false,"loginId":null},{"ipid":13,"startIp":"172.16.0.1000","endIp":"172.16.255.255","allow":0,"allowNull":false,"description":"Faculty ip range ","roomId":0,"roomIdNull":false,"fromDate":null,"toDate":null,"userId":0,"userIdNull":true,"roleName":null,"userRoleId":0,"userRoleIdNull":true,"loginId":null},{"ipid":18,"startIp":"172.16.174.40","endIp":"172.16.174.40","allow":1,"allowNull":false,"description":"Faculty IP Range","roomId":12,"roomIdNull":false,"fromDate":null,"toDate":null,"userId":0,"userIdNull":true,"roleName":"Faculty","userRoleId":4,"userRoleIdNull":false,"loginId":null},{"ipid":20,"startIp":"192.168.1.12","endIp":"192.168.3.35","allow":0,"allowNull":false,"description":"","roomId":0,"roomIdNull":false,"fromDate":null,"toDate":null,"userId":0,"userIdNull":true,"roleName":null,"userRoleId":0,"userRoleIdNull":true,"loginId":null},{"ipid":21,"startIp":"1.1.1.1","endIp":"192.168.1.255","allow":0,"allowNull":false,"description":"","roomId":0,"roomIdNull":true,"fromDate":null,"toDate":null,"userId":0,"userIdNull":true,"roleName":null,"userRoleId":0,"userRoleIdNull":true,"loginId":null}],"recordsTotal":6}
```

Comment: Have you looked into, or tried, jsp tags that would allow `if` constructs for exposing certain buttons? That would be server-side.

Comment: There is always ways for a client to manipulate the DOM, so its is best to double check the roles when POSTED back to the server.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: if we put if else then how can it added in server side pagination column.